# How to get the IP address of DNS Nameserver

Tags: dns

When I do an nslookup on the net. zone, I get the following output:

```
nslookup -type=soa net 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
net
    origin = a.gtld-servers.net
    mail addr = nstld.verisign-grs.com
    serial = 1542217316
    refresh = 1800
    retry = 900
    expire = 604800
    minimum = 86400

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

This means that in order to get DNS records for the net. zone, one should query the DNS Server a.gtld-servers.net. However, the IP Address of a.gtld-servers.net is not given. This results in a catch-22, because in order to get the IP address of any subzone in the net. zone, one should query a.gtld-servers.net.

So my question is, how to get out of this catch-22? How can I get the IP address of a.gtld-servers.net without having to do another DNS request?

Answer (score 1):

The root server addresses can be found in a [file downloaded from iana](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/files)

> This means that in order to get DNS records for the net. zone, one should query the DNS Server a.gtld-servers.net

You could, and at least initially, probably would, but the root servers don't move around frequently, so once you got the ip address for .net server, for example, you would use the cached value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my computer doesn't have the file from iana and Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8) doesn't have it. So how can my computer get the ip address for .net server the first time? And more specifically: can I execute a command to get the actual IP Address?

Comment: Google doesn't have the file for you to download, but they do know the address and use it when you do a lookup.

Comment: I see, so if I would do a -type=a lookup on the nameserver a.gtld-servers.net, I get the address. Thanks again, Terry. Much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, unless you have a special need of some sort, these aren't things you would normally need to deal with. You would use your ISP's DNS server or another public DNS server and they would handle your request.

Comment: True, but I just wanted to know how the black box works. Plus it might be interested for my AWS exam of which Route 53 is a topic.

Comment: All recursive nameservers are shipped with a given list of root servers (and their IPv4+IPv6 addresses) and at boot they will "prime" the root by querying any of known nameserver to grab the list of current root nameservers, in order to accomodate for changes. There are rare but do exist. Like in average at least one IPv4 or IPv6 address change per year.

Comment: And there are thus other ways to get the list, besides HTTPS access. `dig . @a.root-servers.net NS` will also give it.